# Block Diagram Reduction feedforward

Tags: block-diagram

How to solve this block diagram. I am only having difficulty with G3?[image: Block diagram]

Comment: Show what you have calculated the gain to be in the absence of G3 i.e. if you are only having problems with G3, what are the node equations without G3? You need to show some effort because this site is not a free homework answering service.

Comment: Do G1, G2 first. Then G3. Do G4 last. Split the left most summing junction into two pieces and connect G3 to inner and G4 to outer summing junction after it is split up.

Comment: Same comment as earlier - you need to show some work if you want this answering.